# document.getElementByIdContains?

Tags: javascript

Is there, by any chance, a way to solve this problem:

I have elements that have IDs such as "x_y_z". The unique part is "x_y", thus there is no two items that have the same combination of x and y..

However, using getElementById won't work because when I do it I only have the "x" and "y" part and not the Z (think of Z as a random incremental counter).

Is there a way around this? So that when I have the "x" and "y" I say something like getElementByIdContains("x_y")?

Thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

While the answers below suggesting jQuery's ["attribute-starts-with selector"](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/) are correct *(and useful: be sure to check them out!)*, it is not magic. There is no reason to include 78k of JS to perform this query if you don't already have it included.

```
document.getElementsByIdPrefix = function( idPrefix, tagName ){
  if (!tagName) tagName = '*';
  if (document.querySelectorAll){
    return document.querySelectorAll(tagName+"[id^="+idPrefix+"]");
  }else{
    var all = document.getElementsByTagName(tagName);
    var results = [];
    for (var i=0,len=all.length;i<len;++i){
      if (all[i].id.indexOf(idPrefix)==0) results.push(all[i]);
    }
    return results;
  }
}
...
var xys = document.getElementsByIdPrefix( 'x_y', 'input' );
```

With either jQuery or this, you will improve your performance if you can supply a tag name that all the elements will share.

***Edit**: Added performance improvement to use `document.querySelectorAll` when present.*

Comment: Better: `tagName = tagName || '*';`

Comment: You'll want to check for `querySelectorAll` support as well.

Comment: So I put this function in my script section, and I did a call to it this way: var theobject=getElementsByLeadingId("12_43"); alert(theobject[0].name)    but it didn't work..

Comment: @ŠimeVidas I'm curious as to why you would suggest this. Though this is more similar in format to the Ruby idiom of `tagName ||= '*'`, I once polled some JavaScript experts and they suggested that the form I've used here is more accepted in the JS community. It also seems to me to be possibly more performant: with your suggestion an assignment occurs even when not needed. _(I don't know which, if any, modern JS interpreters may optimize this away, however.)_

Comment: @Phrogz jQuery is tested in dozens of browsers, and on different platforms. Additionally, a large community tracks bugs. This makes the jQuery source code exceptionally reliable in "problematical" browsers. Is your code reliable in those browsers? I like native JS code (trust me), but 78k - actually 26k - is a small price for reliability and it is most reasonable to pay it.

Comment: @ŠimeVidas You're generally "preaching to the choir" here: I love jQuery and use it in almost all my endeavors. And the bit about testing is crucial, as evidenced by the OP claiming that the code I supplied doesn't work. :) However, I think it's important for new coders to understand that it provides some nice abstractions on top of the DOM and JavaScript, but does not do things that cannot be done without it.

Comment: @johnshaddad Note that `id` attributes starting with a number are syntactically invalid, and have been shown to cause problems in some browsers. You should prefix those all with at least one letter first.

Comment: @Phrogz Hm, I picked up this usage pattern from Crockford. He calls it the "default" operator: if an argument is passed in, use it. Otherwise, retreat to the default value (the second operand) which is '*'. I wouldn't go into performance - there shouldn't be a relevant difference. However, a best practice is to never write block-less compound statements. So your code is: ` if (!tagName) { tagName = '*'; }`.

Comment: @ŠimeVidas Thanks for the Crockford note. I'll have to look that up and put him on the scales tipping in favor of that idiom :) Oh, and I spit in the face of that particular "best practice" (with no offense whatsover intended to you) :). It is my personal opinion that bracket-less statements are forbidden when the statement is on a new line, but permitted on a single line. I've even been known to do `for (...) if (...) foo();` =:o

Comment: @Phrogz thanks yes I do start the ids with a word first followed by the numbers..

Comment: @johnshaddad Oh, OK, good; I was thrown by your comment above, thinking you had copy/pasted your actual test code.

Comment: @Phrogz Single-line block-less compound-statements? Agreed.

Comment: @Phrogz jQuery **does** do things that cannot be done without it. Actually, one thing - it makes your code reliable. Admit it! :) Your vanilla JS code will always be less reliable than the equivalent jQuery code. Don't underestimate reliability. This is especially important for beginners. Yes, they should learn JS beyond jQuery. But they should **not** disregard jQuery (which is what your answer suggests).

Comment: How is `$("input[id^=x_y]");` more readable than `document.getElementsByIdPrefix( 'x_y', 'input' );`? That jQuery snippet is almost perl-esque in its crypticness to the laymen.

Comment: A really big +1 for *not* giving a jQuery solution when one was not requested.

Comment: @MooGoo It's not more readable. Nobody is claiming that it is.

Comment: @Šime Vidas Sorry, I read "it makes your code *readable* " or something in your comment. I need to stop posting after midnight...

Answer (score 3):

If you can use jquery, use jquery wild card selector -

```
$("input[id^=x_y]");
```

http://www.emadibrahim.com/2009/07/25/jquery-wildcard-selector/

Otherwise, you have to fetch all elements (of that particular tag) and check them whether they are a match.

Comment: +1 However, that selector's name is "Attribute Starts With Selector" http://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/

Comment: Thanks. It is an ID for a input field, would I still need "div"? What should it be?

Comment: @john No, you don't need the div part. You can instead use `input` or even `input:text` if it's a text-box, or just leave it empty (use only the [id..] part)

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the jQuery libray, it's selectors have the ability to do just what you want.

http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/